# CSS High precision measurements, inputs, simple form

Tags: css

I am firts know.

Can someone modify this example for me, but that the measurements are totally exact in horizontal? (and auto ajust size screen offcourse).

[image]

Code:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQ2J7FETCPBY

Very thanks.

Comment: please, elaborate what you want

Answer (score 2):

add css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Nice! very thanks.

Comment: @motocross If this is the correct answer that worked for you, please click that tick below to approve it.